# rails : running rake task in cron job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, cron, rake

I am trying to run rake task in cron job like this

```
0 * * * *  cd /var/www/rails_path/rails && rake my_task RAILS_ENV=production
```

I can run this command

```
cd /var/www/rails_path/rails && rake my_task RAILS_ENV=production
```

from shell and got result.

And I checked the cron log the commond did get run. But in fact the rake task didn't get run when the cron job excutes (the task should have logs, I didn't see logs of this rake task after cron job ran).

What is the issue?

**UPDATED:**

tried

```
0 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c "cd /var/www/rails_path/rails && rake my_task RAILS_ENV=production"
```

no luck

installed `whenever` gem and have

```
every 2.minutes do
   rake "my_task"
end
```

in ./config/schdule.rb. It was not running at all (I deployed rails in nginx with passenger).

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

`0 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd your_app_path && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake your_task'`

Or, it is good to use [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem if you want to do command line rails work in cron.

Comment: Thanks, Does whenever work well with passenger? I tried rufus-scheduler, which seems not working very well with passenger

Comment: I tested whenever in nginx+puma and nginx+unicorn but not tested with passenger. But I think it'll work, because there is no issue about passenger in whenever github page, unlike in rufus-scheduler page.